# Scroll event changes state automatically on React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

I am doing a lazyload paging with API requests.

Basically I have an input API request function and scroll API request function. when I search something by using input API request is starting to work at the background and it takes a while because there are a lot of data in API. So when it works I am changing the isloading state to true because I don't want to do any API request by scrolling event until the request which one comes by input function finish . However when I scroll the page while API request still working isloading state changing false automatically despite I changed it to true before.

How can I pass that? Appreciated

```
  const[isloading , setIsloading] = useState(false);

 const onChange = (e) =>{
clearTimeout(timeout);

timeout = setTimeout(function () {
  setChecked(false);
  setCounter(0)
  setCards([])
  let new_payload = payload;
  new_payload.skip = 0
  
  if(isloading === false){
    fetching.postData(e.target.value , new_payload, true)
    setSearchInputValue(e.target.value)
    setIsloading(true)
  }
  } , 1000);


window.addEventListener('scroll' , ()=>{
let screen_height = window.innerHeight;
let scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
var body = document.body,
html = document.documentElement;

var body_heigth = Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, 
                  html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight );

console.log(isloading)  
let is_loading = isloading
if(scrollTop + 1 > body_heigth - screen_height && is_loading === false && checked === false){ 
  is_loading = true
  setIsloading(is_loading)
  postData(searchInputValue , payload)
}
})
```

Comment: I believe that your event listener is added more than once

Comment: I am pretty sure it doesn't. It is not a big project so I can easily check on it.

Comment: Every time `onChange` event is fired a new event listener is added

Comment: I took it into useEffect. But it still does. I believe the problem is because of the states works asynchronous. That's why when I use an event listener it takes prevState situation. So I created an useRef data with state and I changed it to true instead of isloading in postData function. Then I checked isloading and useRef data is same? And BINGO! they are not. And I added an controll that if they're not same do not send API request. It works!

Answer (score 0):

That `window.addEventListener('scroll', () => ...)` must be inside a `useEffect`, and that `useEffect` should have `isLoading` as a dependency.

Here's a simplified example:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = React.useState('');
  
  const fakeFetchData = React.useCallback(() => {
    console.log('fakeFetchData');
    
    setIsLoading(true);
      
    window.setTimeout(() => {
      setData(Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 5));
      setIsLoading(false);
    }, 3000);
  }, []);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    fakeFetchData();
  }, [fakeFetchData]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    function handleScroll() {
      console.log(`isLoading = ${ isLoading }`);
      
      if (!isLoading) { 
        fakeFetchData();
      }
    }
    
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    };
  }, [isLoading, fakeFetchData]);

  return (
    <div className="app">    
      <div className="data">
        { isLoading ? ' Loading...' : ` ${ data }` }
      </div>      
    </div>
  );
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector('#app'));

root.render(<App />);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
  margin: 0;
}

.app {
  height: 500vh;
}

.data {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Yes that was the first thing what I did and it still didn't work because states work asynchronous

Comment: @ctamyildirim Check the example I added.